# How to get the where clause with a bind variable to work in php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
function get_grade($sku) {
    require("config.php");
    try {

        $results = $db -> query prepare ("SELECT name, subject1,grade1,attendance,gender,subject2,grade2,subject3,grade3 FROM student WHERE sku = ?"); //binds the sku to the question mark
        $results -> bindParam;
        $results -> execute();
    }
    catch exception ($e) {
        echo "could not connect";
        exit;
    }
    $product = $results-> fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASOC);
}
```

How to get a where clause to work, where if the user has the same or similar attendance, subjects and grades then they will get then they will get that grade from a past student.

Comment: You have not finished `$results->bindParam....` which is how to get your `WHERE` clause to work. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind `$sku`:

```
$results->bindParam(1, $sku);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
function get_grade($sku) {
    require("config.php");

    try {

        $results = $db->prepare("SELECT name, subject1,grade1,attendance,gender,subject2,grade2,subject3,grade3 FROM student WHERE sku = :sku"); 
                     //^^^^^^^^Perpare statement here                                                                                  //^^^^Placeholder for variable
        $results->execute(array("sku" => $sku));
                        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^Instead of binParam

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
           //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Catch PDO exeption
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    $product = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASOC);


}
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP what you did, and why.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Wrote a few comments what i changed